# My Vulkan application is locked at 30 fps on an Nvidia GPU, but not on an Intel iGPU

Tags: c++, vulkan, vsync

I have followed the tutorial [vulkan-tutorial.com](http://vulkan-tutorial.com) and after reaching the point of having a spinnig square in 3D space I decided to measure the performance of the program. I'm working on a laptop with both an Nvidia GTX 1050 GPU and an Intel UHD Graphics 620 GPU. I have added the function to manually pick the GPU that the program should use.

When I pick the 1050 I get a stable 30fps for my 4 vertices and 6 indices. Seems underperforming to me so I figured the frames must be locked at 30 by Vsync. I have tried to disable Vsync for all applications in the GeForce control panel, but I'm still locked at 30 fps. I also tried to disable Vsync in the application by changing the present mode to always be `VK_PRESENT_MODE_IMMEDIATE_KHR`, but still 30fps.

When I choose the Intel GPU i get over 3000fps no problem, with or without Vsync enabled.

The .cpp file for the application can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/ihLSxYzE), and the .h file [here](https://pastebin.com/ccJQquB6), and the main file to run [here](https://pastebin.com/wYFbA8C4). The shaders are [here](https://pastebin.com/i4YPTSYm).

Console output when choosing the 1050:
[image: GTX 1050]

Console output when choosing the iGPU:
[image: iGPU]

Comment: FIFO mode locks presentation with Vsync. I assume that changing settings in GeForce control panel doesn't influence Vulkan applications. Immediate mode presents image on screen as soon as it is presented. It doesn't wait for a Vsync signal. So I'd assume that there may be a bug in a graphics driver.